# How to put process into background after it takes data from user in bash

Tags: bash, background-process

I would like to run process `process_name` which takes data from the user one after another with different `-b` an `-e` options as shown below.
Now, the thing is that I want those processes running in background so I can run `process_name -b 100 -e 200` just after `process_name -b 0 -e 100`.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

while [ $i -lt 1000 ]
do

#  echo "$i"
 j=$[$i + 100]

 process_name -b $i -e $j

 i=$[$i + 100]

done
```

How can I do it without using nohup, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution is to add "&" at the end of command:

```
process_name -b $i -e $j &
```

your processes will go in background just after execution. You'll find all running jobs with "ps" or "jobs" commands.

Comment: Well, I tried this and this does not work as I expect, because when process goes into background it does not prompt the user to input the data.

Comment: you are right, I misunderstood the question. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution satisfying me. Namely I just redirect standard input for `process_name`, with:

```
process_name -b $i -e $j < input.txt &
```